# PHP Broadcast Calendar

Tags: php, calendar

In the television industry, they use a Broadcast Calendar, it differs from the Gregorian Calendar in the way that the days from the previous month are pulled in to create the current month. Each month has exactly 4 or 5 weeks and the week always starts on a Monday.

There is more information about this Calendar here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_calendar

[Updated Broadcast Calendar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhzk0.png)

I am trying to achieve three things:

1) A PHP function where I can feed it a specific date and have it return what Broadcast **month** it is.

```
function getBroadcastMonth('2019-10-16'){
   //Return broadcast month
   return 10;
}
```

2) A PHP function where I can feed it a specific date and have it return what Broadcast **week** it is.

```
function getBroadcastWeek('2019-10-16'){
   //Return broadcast week
   return 42;
}
```

3) A function where I can get the 1st and last day of the Broadcast month.

```
function getFirstAndLast(10){
   //Return first and last day of the given broadcast month
   return array('first_day' => '2019-09-30', 'end' => '2019-10-27');
}
```

I tried to construct a function to at least build a Calendar in an array, so I could somehow use it to get the result I need, however I did not get very far. Here is that code.

```
$now = new DateTime();

$from = (new DateTime)->setISODate($now->format('Y') - 1, 1);
$from->modify("monday this week"); // see ISO 8601 

while($from < $now) {
    echo $from->format('W  --  d/M/Y').'<br />';
    $from->modify("+1 week");
}
```

Is anybody able to help me with this?

[There is a further example here of how this can be done in SQL Server.](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/broadcast-calender-generator)

Comment: I think the easiest way to begin would be to write some tests to specifically illustrate the *exact* requirements of this function.  For example, January 7, 2019 should be week 2?  (Or is it zero-based index, so week 1?)  And, how do you plan to handle DST?

Comment: I'm confused. According to the Wikipedia article, March 1 should be in the first week of March, but in your image it's in the last week of February.

Comment: Your right Nick, I think that Calendar was generated incorrectly. If you look at ones from the official source it has the first being in March. https://www.rab.com/public/reports/broadcastCalendar.cfm. I will update the example.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be zero based. Most I have seen would have it start at 1. I am not sure what you mean by DST. I don't think that will effect it will it?

Comment: @zamtime address your comments to particular people by putting an `@` in front of their name (as I have done in this comment). As soon as you type `@` you will get offered a list of names to use.

Comment: @Nick, thanks for the tip. I found this article on sql central that does exactly what I need, but I was hoping to do it in PHP as I feel like it would kill the database the way I need to use it. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/broadcast-calender-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a set of functions that will do what you want. You might want to consider wrapping them into a class... and there is undoubtedly some optimisation that could be done.

```
function makeBroadcastCalendar($start_date, $end_date) {
    $end = new DateTime($end_date);
    $start = new DateTime($start_date);
    $start->modify('monday this week');
    $week = 1;
    $weeks = array();
    while($start < $end) {
        $weeks[$week++] = $start->format('Y-m-d');
        $start->modify('+1 week');
    }
    return $weeks;
}

function getBroadcastMonth($date) {
    $end_of_week = new DateTime($date);
    $end_of_week->modify('sunday this week');
    return (int)$end_of_week->format('n');
}

function getBroadcastWeek($date) {
    $start = new DateTime($date);
    $start->modify('January 1');
    $start->modify('monday this week');
    $start_of_week = new DateTime($date);
    $start_of_week->modify('monday this week');
    $week = 1;
    while ($start < $start_of_week) {
        $start->modify('+1 week');
        $week++;
    }
    return $week;
}

function getFirstAndLast($year, $month) {
    $start = new DateTime("$year-$month-01");
    $end = clone $start;
    $start->modify('monday this week');
    $output = array('first_day' => $start->format('Y-m-d'));
    $end->modify('+1 month');
    $end->modify('monday this week');
    while ($start < $end) {
        $start->modify('+1 week');
    }
    $output['end'] = $start->modify('-1 day')->format('Y-m-d');
    return $output;
}
```

You can see them in operation in this [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/llVTN)

Comment: @zamtime no worries - It was an interesting question. As I said, some of the code could probably use some optimisation but this should be a good starting point.